# rails ActiveRecord includes method with where : where not applied in subsequent calls to get associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have 2 tables *as* and *bs* in a many-to-many relationship with a join table. The join table has an attribute *cond*.

The records are as follows:

as:

```
id
1
```

abs:

```
id  a_id  b_id  cond
1   1     1     1
2   1     1     0
```

bs:

```
id
1
```

Now I do:

> b = A.find(1).bs.where(:abs => {:cond => 1}).includes(:abs).first

Which gives me my *b* instance, the question is, why does *b.abs* return **all** *abs* rows?

I thought the *includes* method was meant to avoid reloading associations in subsequent calls to the associations methods. Since I used a *where* in the first call I would expect *b.abs* to return only the row with *cond == 1*.

I tried this in the rails console and no SQL request is issued when I perform the *b.abs* call. What is happening here? Is there a way to do what I want or do I need to put the condition again on *b.abs* like *b.abs.where(:abs => {:cond => 1}) ?

As requested in the comments, here is the code for the models:

cat app/models/a.rb

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bs, :through => :abs
    has_many :abs   
end
```

cat app/models/b.rb

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :as, :through => :abs
    has_many :abs 
end
```

cat app/models/ab.rb

```
class Ab < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cond, :a_id, :b_id
    belongs_to :a
    belongs_to :b
end
```

Comment: could you post the code of both models ?

Comment: sure, I added it to the original post